# Using jointjs in angular2/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, jointjs

me and my friend would like to use `jointjs`, which is written in JavaScript, in `angular2/typescript`. We tried various tutorials on how to import `javascript` libraries in typescript, but nothing really worked for us/jointjs. Is there something special we have to consider when importing `jointjs`?

Greetings

Comment: Do you have any particular error message? Please describe what did you try and the result of it.

Comment: We always got the error 'cannot find module xxx'. We simply tried all sorts of different ways to import the libraries (we can't really remember everything we tried). Is it possible to import javascript libraries in typescript without having a type definition file for the library?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the jointjs typings?

```
typings install jointjs --save
```

That should probably get rid of the error message.

To import the library in a typescript class this should work:

```
import * as jointjs from 'jointjs';
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
import * as joint from 'joint';

export class JointAwareClass {
  joint:any = joint;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Now when creating your main component, extend it:

```
export class AppComponent extends JointAwareClass  {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Sadly it isnt working either. When we try to import joint (import * as joint from 'joint';), like you mentioned we get the message: "Cannot find module 'joint'". 
Instead of 'joint' we also tried this '../../../node_modules/jointjs/index.js' and this '../../../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js' with the same result.The index.js we refered to in our first path, simply contains "module.exports = require()'./dist/joint';" if this is helping in any way.

Comment: @AngJobs please can you provide a more descriptive example